# Why is Solr returning results that are negated?

Tags: solr

Consider the following Solr query:

```
text:linux -img_src:jpg -img_src:jpeg -img_src:youtube
```

Solr is still returning results that have the negated terms in the `img_src` field:

```
  <doc>
    <str name="img_src">
      http://lh3.ggpht.com/-zek96i2kouM/R9HZD2U-d9I/AAAAAAAAC7Q/Zf_QHmiL10w/Stress.jpg
    </str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="img_src">
      http://lh3.ggpht.com/-zek96i2kouM/R9HZD2U-d9I/AAAAAAAAC7Q/Zf_QHmiL10w/Stress.jpg
    </str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="img_src">
      http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8436/7787223734_5962d16624.jpg
    </str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="img_src">
      http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7246/7787084482_8ee833cc45.jpg
    </str>
  </doc>
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. What might that be? Thanks.

Comment: perhaps try something like `text:linux AND -img_src:jpg AND -img_src:jpeg AND -img_src:youtube`.  Or `q=text:linux&fq=-img_src:jpg&fq=-img_src:jpeg&fq=-img_src:youtube`

Comment: Thanks, Frank. Adding the `AND` separators did not help, but the faceted search did. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problems.  I believe I used [filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to achieve the desired results, e.g.:

```
 ?q=text:linux&fq=-img_src:jpg&fq=-img_src:jpeg&fq=-img_src:youtube
```